# Struggling to add data to PostgreSQL table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Trying to add many columns to the database

```
sql = " INSERT into logs (ip, time, request, error_code, system_info) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) "
cur.executemany(sql, values)
```

and got a mistake relationship "logs" does not exist
but this table exists in [PgAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRkSY.png)

when I try to add brackets to the table name

```
sql = " INSERT into "logs" (ip, time, request, error_code, system_info) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) "
```

I got an invalid syntax mistake

values variable is a list of tuples, looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqkL1.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The table "logs" doesn't exist in the search_path your program is using on the database it is connected to.  PgAdmin is using a different schema, or a different database, or different instance, or different server entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Change the external quotes to single quotes, in that way you can use the double quotes inside the  string.

```
sql = 'INSERT into "logs" (ip, time, request, error_code, system_info) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
```

Or you can use the backslash to escape the character:

```
sql = "INSERT into \"logs\" (ip, time, request, error_code, system_info) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but i got the same mistake (

Comment: Have you checked the connection to the database before execute?

Comment: thanks, I decided on the issue in another way. I created a new table inside my code, not in the PGadmin query tool and it works. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: If that was successful, then either it had never been created via PGadmin  nor any other way, or you were on the wrong database/schema. After a table is created Postgres does not know nor care how it was created just that it was created. Your initial error message was correct *the table did not exist*.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
`'INSERT INTO public."logs"( ip, time, request, error_code, system_info) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);'`